# Match array of strings to 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a `1D` array of strings (`gene_name_list`). I need to find rows in another `2D` array (`fully_split`) where each string of the first array is present. Of course I can solve it brute force like that:

```
longest_gene_name = len(max(gene_name_list, key=len))
ensembl_list = np.full((len(gene_name_list)), '', dtype='U{}'.format(longest_gene_name))
for idx, gene_name in enumerate(gene_name_list):  
    for row in fully_split:                       
        if gene_name in row:                      
            ensembl_list[idx] = row[0]
```

But it takes too long, I need a faster solution.

`row[0]` contains special symbols that I am mapping to. So, if a string is found, it will be found in `row[1:]` portion, and then I am taking `row[0]`. Not relevant, but to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I am making a couple assumptions:
- The 2d array is rectangular (i.e. not `dtype=object`) since NumPy performance would be useless otherwise.
- `len(fully_split) == len(gene_name_list)` since your code example has `ensembl_list[idx] = row[0]` and `idx` is derived from `gene_name_list`

```
>>> gene_name_list = np.array('a bb c d eee'.split())

>>> fully_split = np.array([
...     'id1 a bb c d eee'.split(), # yes
...     'id2 f g hh iii j'.split(),
...     'id3 kk ll a nn o'.split(), # yes
...     'id4 q rr c t eee'.split(), # yes
...     'id5 v www xx y z'.split()
... ])

>>> longest_gene_name = len(max(gene_name_list, key=len))

>>> dtype = 'U{}'.format(longest_gene_name)

>>> ensembl_list = np.zeros_like(gene_name_list, dtype=dtype)

>>> mask = np.isin(fully_split, gene_name_list).any(axis=1)

>>> ensembl_list[mask] = fully_split[mask, 0]

>>> ensembl_list
array(['id1', '', 'id3', 'id4', ''], dtype='<U3')
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the answer. The only problem is that `np.isin` is not present in earlier `numpy` versions and I am using `python 2.7`. Makes sense to rewrite it then with `in1d` somehow...

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L600-L696) for `np.isin` it is pretty much a 1-liner to implement (assuming the invert parameter introduced in v1.8.0 is available with python 2.7).

Answer (score 1):

Execution time apart, I don't think the brute force method you posted corresponds to what you describe in words:

> I need to find rows in another 2D array where **each string** of the first array is present.

Your code at best finds all the rows there **at least one** of the strings of the 1D array is present in the row of the 2D array.

The  following code does what you asked in words using regex.

```
import re

pattern = r'*'.join(map(re.escape, np.sort(gene_name_list)))
rows = [''.join(np.sort(x)) for x in fully_split]
res = [re.search(pattern, r) for r in rows]
```

Since order is not relevant, the `gene_name_list` is lexicographically sorted and strings are concatenated using the regex special char `'*'` as delimitator. This is the pattern which will be searched.
Then each row of the 2D array `fully_split` is again lexicographically sorted and the strings joined to form a single string. A regex search is performed on each row to check if there is a match.

`res` is a list, you get `None` for those rows where a match is not found, and the corresponding `MatchObject` is a match is found.

This illustrates the concept. To be closer to your expected result (where you store the first element of the row) replace the last line with:

```
res = [l[0] if re.search(pattern, r) else None for r, l in zip(rows, fully_split)]
```